# warning on all custom plugins

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-eclipse-plugin

All my custom component in dart using dart-eclipse plugins have warning saying that the 
component cannot be found. For example

```dart
<paper-input floatinglabel multiline
  id = 'description-ppr-input'
  class = 'sibling-container'
  label = '{{ label }}'
  style = 'width: {{ width }};'
  inputValue = '{{ description.description }}'
  error = '{{ errorMsg }}'>
</paper-input>
```

the first paper-input would be flagged as an 'Unknown tag (paper-input).

My custom tag also have similar warnings.

The application does run normally, its just that the warnings are annoying.

I think it is something related to polymr linter transformer. Is there anyway to get rid of these warnings?

I don't get similar warnings when I am using the stand-alone Dart editor.

Cheers

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but I don't think this is Dart or Dart-plugin related. I have the same in WebStorm. Every custom element and any non-standard attribute is shown with a red line. I can add them to an ignore list but this becomes a huge list and needs to be extended for every new element. I guess this is some other Eclipse plugin that produces these warnings.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Appreciate the help.